# Golang String Enum from medium.com

Tags: go, enums

I try to run the enum string example code from medium.com [How and Why to Write Enums in Go](https://medium.com/qvault/how-and-why-to-write-enums-in-go-9c1a25649df0)
There is an error

> Cannot use '[...]string{"Head", "Shoulder", "Knee", "Toe"}' (type [4]string) as the type string

How to fix that?

```
type BodyPart int

const (
    Head BodyPart = iota // Head = 0
    Shoulder // Shoulder = 1
    Knee // Knee = 2
    Toe // Toe = 3
)

func (bp BodyPart) String() string {
    return [...]string{"Head", "Shoulder", "Knee", "Toe"}
}
```

Comment: Don’t trust random code from the internet. Case in point: That code is broken. Find some other example.

Comment: I’m guessing the code is missing a `[bp]` at the end, but I wouldn’t call it an elegant implementation. I’m sure there are better examples out there.

Comment: Ah okay. Thank you for your answer and your assessment. :)

Answer (score 1):

What autor of blogpost probably wanted to demonstrate is that you can use numeric constants instead of storing strings and print them out nicely "as strings" by implementing [`Stringer` interface](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Stringer):

```golang
type BodyPart int
const (
    Head BodyPart = iota // Head = 0
    Shoulder // Shoulder = 1
    Knee // Knee = 2
    Toe // Toe = 3
)

func (bp BodyPart) String() string {
    return []string{"Head", "Shoulder", "Knee", "Toe"}[bp]
}

func main() {
  bp := Shoulder
  fmt.Println(bp) // will print: Shoulder
}
```

Comment: Does this work with marshalling/unmarshalling JSON fields?

Comment: @wheeler your question is a bit vague - it depends on what is actual JSON value